# JS is not reading my env variable correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I have the following code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();


function distribute_timeout() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    let timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() *
      (process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MAX - process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MIN + 1) +
      process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MIN);
    console.log(timeout);
    distribute_timeout();
  }, 2000);
}

distribute_timeout()
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
1
4
```

My .env file:

```
RANDOM_TIME_MIN=3
RANDOM_TIME_MAX=9
```

So "timeout" should print a number between 3 and 9. The thing is, it works perfectly fine when I replace my .env variables in the code like that:

```js
require('dotenv').config();


function distribute_timeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        let timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 3 + 1) + 3);
        console.log(timeout);
        distribute_timeout();
    }, 2000);
}

distribute_timeout()
```

Output:

```
6
9
5
3
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This is completely strange behavior. When I log the .env variables, the value is set and printed out. But when it should be used in the calculation, it is ignored...

EDIT:
Apparently, I just needed to typecast the values to Number.

Comment: So [do some basic debugging first](/help/how-to-ask): what _are_ the values that get used in your code? Because you almost certainly don't need our help, you just need to discover what your code's doing. Console log your `process.env`: are the values there? Are they correct? Then do some targeted logging: are they the right type so that `+` will do what it's supposed to? And if the values _aren't_ there: the dotenv config function can take a `{ path: ... }` to explicitly load a specific file, so what happens when you point it to your `.env` file's absolute (_not_ relative) path?

Comment: I already debugged the code for hours. The values are there, I can print them, and they are numbers. When used in my calculations they are present, but sometimes just ignored.. I thought maybe this is some strange js behaviour.

Comment: (And if you do any of that, and you should, remember to put that information in your post. Don't tell "me" the results in a comment, these are details everyone reading your post should see)

Comment: then put that in your post. _Show us_ that you're console logging them by having code for that in your post, along with the resultant console output in the output blocks. Because unless you show proof, it's usually not enough to just claim you did a thing. Especially because "I can print them, and they are numbers." doesn't tell you enough: just because something prints as a number does not mean it _is_ a number. Both `3` and `"3"` print as 3. Use `typeof` to check.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I'm pretty new to stack overflow, and I will do it better next time. Thanks! The typecasting solved the problem.

Comment: Of course, but you would have discovered you needed to turn the string into a number if you had actually console logged both the values, and their type yourself. A simple `dotenv.config(); console.log(process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MIN, typeof process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MIN, process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MAX, typeof process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MAX);` would have solved this without even needing to ask for help, which is why debugging is so important. First making sure you _actually_ know what all your data is solved the problem before you ever need to write a post =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure they are returned as numbers and not strings? And you have a missing semicolon btw!

Maybe type-casting the returned values as numbers will help...

```
let timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Number(process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MAX) - Number(process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MIN) + 1) + Number(process.env.RANDOM_TIME_MIN));
```

But start by putting the semicolon in its place first!

Comment: Thank you! Typecasting solved it!